# Matlab movie show 2 plots

Tags: matlab, movie, matlab-figure

I have a y matrix that is a 1001x2 and each column represents the phase angle of an oscillator. I'm trying to make a matlab movie so that I plot both phase angles at time t for times, one at a time. So basically it should look like 2 points moving around in circles. If I hold on the plot then it seems to be right, except at all the points are on the frames. But if I dont hold on, then only the second plot gets shown in each iteration (there is only a red * every frame). Any idea whats going on and how I can make both points get shown on each frame?

```
fig1=figure(1);
winsize = get(fig1,'Position');
winsize(1:2) = [0 0];
numframes=100;
A=moviein(numframes,fig1,winsize);
set(fig1,'NextPlot','replacechildren')
i=1;

%hold on
for frame=1:numframes
i=frame*10;
plot(cos(mod(y(i),2*pi)),sin(mod(y(i),2*pi)),'bo');
plot(cos(mod(y(i,2),2*pi)) *1.1,sin(mod(y(i,2),2*pi))*1.15,'r*'); %only this one is shown
axis([-1.5 1.5 -1.5 1.5])
A(:,i)=getframe(fig1,winsize);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you can `hold on` during the frame drawing and `hold off` at the end of the frame drawing. like

```
 for frame=1:numframes
 i=frame*10;

 plot(cos(mod(y(i),2*pi)),sin(mod(y(i),2*pi)),'bo');   
 hold on   % // here
 plot(cos(mod(y(i,2),2*pi)) *1.1,sin(mod(y(i,2),2*pi))*1.15,'r*');
 axis([-1.5 1.5 -1.5 1.5])
 A(:,i)=getframe(fig1,winsize);
 hold off  % // and here
 end
```

but in this case you can simply do

```
 ....
 plot(cos(mod(y(i),2*pi)),sin(mod(y(i),2*pi)),'bo', ... 
     cos(mod(y(i,2),2*pi)) *1.1,sin(mod(y(i,2),2*pi))*1.15,'r*');
```

Comment: Tried that before asking the question here and didn't work. It just shows as if I did the `hold on` before the loop.

Comment: you have to put it in between... btw the second strategy will work. You may want to add a `sleep(.01)` (for vision ease) or something between the frames.

Comment: Yes, the second strategy did work. But I still dont understand why the first one didn't. Any ideas?

Comment: because the `hold on` and `hold off` are run sequentially during the loops, thus they *cancel* each other. And just the state `on`, which is called first, holds.

Comment: Well, now I have an arbitrary (large) number of columns, so using the second strategy isn't feasible. What I have in mind is just to loop through all the columns and plot them, while holding on. But this requires something like the first strategy,  but I cant see to make it work. Any ideas?

Comment: @sazpaz, Well what's the problem so? Did you use the sleep as I suggested?

Comment: I still didn't get to plot many series while `holding on`. I used a  `scatter` plot instead. You might enjoy the output of this code. It's a Kuramoto model. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHR07OZIbWY

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20526/discussion-between-sazpaz-and-acorbe)